# Android Location Based services to know if location details received from GPS or AGPS

Tags: android, gps

I have used a case to know if the location services returned by Android Location API's is from GPS or AGPS. i.e I want to know if the user is Indoor or Outdoor.

Is there a way to get this details from location APIs?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

You are confusing alternative location providers, such as WLAN and GSM Cell locationing with assisted GPS. Assited GPS means speed up of receiveing detailied satelitte positions (ephemeris) by downloading them via Internet instead receiving them via GPS Satellites.

So you probably want to know whetehr a position was delivered by SateliteNavigation(GPS) or by alternate locationing technic:

If you want to know whether a position was delivered by GPS_PROVIDER or by Wlan or GSM (= NETWORK_PROVIDER) then you can check the course and speed and accuracy attributes.

if accuracy < 30: from GPS
if speed and course is set to any valid value: GPS, because GPS is the only service that delivers course and speed.